# Why is my body always empty on making a post call from react js front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, post

React js:

```
export const insertUser=( name, facebookId )=> {
    return (dispatch) => {
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/insertUser", {
            method: "post",
            credentials: 'same-origin',
            mode: 'no-cors',
            redirect: 'follow',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Origin': '',
            },

            body: JSON.stringify({
                facebookId: facebookId,
                name: name
            }),
        }).then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
        });
    }
}
```

Node js express:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.post('/insertUser, user.createUser);
```

The react js code sends empty body to the backend. If I make the mode: cors, I get a 404.

Comment: Are you able to see body in browser dev console (requests tab)?

Comment: yes i can see the body in the request payload

Comment: Is it normal that you are missing a quote `'` in `app.post('/insertUser, user.createUser);` ?

Comment: @user2452537 can you please add createUser implementation to the question?

Comment: createUser: function createUser(req, res, next) {
        var opt = {
            facebookId: req.body.facebookId,
            name: req.body.name
        }
      //inserting in the db
    },

Comment: @yuantonito that is a copy paste error.Sorry the code works fine with postman  i can  pass the body but breaks when its called from the front end

Answer (score 1):

You are passing data as string and you have configured bodyparser using json.

When you are passing data as string then you should use as text like this :

`app.use(bodyParser.text());`